# What is the difference of SQL Server on EC2 and DBS on Amazon Web Services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have not used AWS yet and want to get to kinda assessment about its data center options.

My guess is that you can have a MySQL or SQL Server on an EC2 virtual box.

If DBS is Amazon data specific service, what are the differences between these two approaches:
Using DBS vs DB on EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806272/what-are-the-respective-advantages-limitations-of-amazon-rds-vs-ec2-with-mysql) first.

According to Amazon's [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/):

> Connect to your DB Instance using your favorite database tool or programming language. Since you have direct access to a native MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server database engine, most tools designed for these engines should work unmodified with Amazon RDS.

Basically, going the EC2 route requires a lot more maintenance in the long run. If you're using Amazon's services, and you need any one of those kind of databases, you might as well use RDS.