# Why should I use AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I installed a LAMP stack in my AWS EC2 instances so that I can use the MySQL server. Somebody recommended using RDS. But RDS is not free and also a MySQL server. My question is what makes RDS so special comparing with my MySQL server in EC2 instances?

Thanks. By the way, I'm quite new to AWS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the respective advantages/limitations of Amazon RDS vs. EC2 with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806272/what-are-the-respective-advantages-limitations-of-amazon-rds-vs-ec2-with-mysql)

Comment: I didn't find this one.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What do you mean by 'But RDS is not free and also a MySQL server'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RDS is a managed solution. Which means, AWS staff will take care of:

- Patches
- Backups
- Maintenance
- Making sure it's alive

Hosting your database in a second EC2 instance means that:

- You have to manage everything of the above

Using a LAMP stack and co-hosting Apache and MySQL is the cheapest, but:

- You have to manage everything of the above
- You're probably hosting a database on an instance exposed to the internet

That said, if you're planning to host a production website / service that's more than a personal website / blog / experiment you'll probably need to host webserver and database in different instances. Picking RDS is less of a headache.

For anything thats *not that important*, a LAMP stack makes more sense. Less scalability, potentially less security but also less administrative overhead and costs.

Comment: This may do more sense when you need to add the second machine with apache/php, if mysql is hosted outside it is possible to maintain the same configuration for both machines. Setup of a FrontEnd security group and Database security groups, permiting access to Database security groups only from FrontEnd machines.