# What is the difference between MySQL database on Amazon EC2 and a MySQL database on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I want a database for my android stock audio store app. I will be storing my audio files on Amazon S3. I need a database for user info and audio meta data, for which I have created a MySQL database on my local pc but I don't know where to host it. Now, I need to know what is the difference between storing it on EC2 and RDS.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2013/05/pros-and-cons-of-rds-vs-ec2-for-mysql-with-aws/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the respective advantages/limitations of Amazon RDS vs. EC2 with MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806272/what-are-the-respective-advantages-limitations-of-amazon-rds-vs-ec2-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

On EC2 you have full control over sql instance, have to manage it by yourself, set up replication if needed, and according to shared responsibility model you are responsible for any security issues.

On RDS your control is limited, AWS upgrades and patches the instance, makes backups, can set up replication, and is responsible for security (except if you compromise your passwords, of course).

Also, performance of the local instance may be higher because of no delay to network transfer, but it certainly depends on your ability to configure it and on EC2 instance load.